# PTIJ: Halachos related to The Magic Mirror

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Does [The Magic Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Mirror_(Snow_White)) have to cover himself when observing Aveilus? Can The Magic Mirror daven in front of other Magic Mirrors, or is that forbidden since one may not daven in front of a mirror ([Mishnah Berurah 90:71](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.90.71))?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).